# Restrict viewing based on Current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm sure this is a silly question with a straight-forward answer, but I can't seem to recall the answer or find it in the Devise docs.

I'm looking for a way to restrict a user from seeing attributes of a record they don't own.  In my application, `users` `have_many :notes` and `notes` `belongs_to :user`.

Right now, a user can look at their own post (`localhost:3000/notes/1`), but they can also view notes by any other user, simply by changing the url to something like `localhost:3000/notes/2`.  I want to prevent that and only allow them the ability to view their own (`~/notes/1` in this example)

Comment: There are some standard gems for this, like `pundit` and `cancan`

Comment: In your controller scope the query to the current user

Answer (score 0):

In the controller action scope the query to the current user, something like

`Note.all.where(user_id: current_user.id)` for index and chain with `.find(id: params[:id])` for actions with single record.

Answer (score 0):

```rb
def show
   @note = @current_user.notes.find_by(id: params[:id])
end
```